# Returning NaN or throwing an exception?

Tags: c++, statistics, numeric, nan

I have a function that gets a sample (an `std::vector<double>`) as input and computes the average of the sample: what is the best way to handle the empty input vector case?

My first idea is to throw an exception like in this snippet:

```
double average(const std::vector<double>& sample)
{
   size_t sz = sample.size();
   if (sz==0) throw std::exception("unexpected empty vector");

   double acc = 0;
   for (size_t i=0; i<sz; ++i) acc += sample[i];
   return acc/sz;
}
```

But I think another solution could be to return NaN:

```
double average(const std::vector<double>& sample)
{
   size_t sz = sample.size();
   if (sz==0) return std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();

   double acc = 0;
   for (size_t i=0; i<sz; ++i) acc += sample[i];
   return acc/sz;
}
```

I like the exception because it shows where the problem happened while if I get a NaN in a final result of a long computation I will have more difficulties to understand where the NaN was born. Anyway with the NaN I like the possibility of returning a "special" double to signal something unexpected happened.

Is there any other way of cope with the empty vector?
Thank you.

Comment: 2 tips: pass the vector by reference (&) and use Kahan summation.

Comment: @ybungalobill +1 for the first tip (I forgot the & I usually write). For the second tip I have a question: have you ever seen real code misbehaving and fix the problem with the Kahan summation?

Comment: define 'misbehaving'. Floating point calculation do not 'misbehave' (usually), they just gradually loose precision. Yes, it's common to sum 100 numbers and get a result far enough from the infinite-precision one so that it's seen in the output.

Comment: I am curious about direct experience (or "War Story") related to numerical analysis, did it happen to code you were working on? How much "far enough" was?

Comment: @uvts_cvs: Ask this as a new question (with a floating point tag).

Comment: @uvts: well I exaggerate. Although you can get 2 decimal places error while summing 100 numbers it's not so common. Here is a real example, summing 1/n^2 with 32-bit precision. Without Kahan it converges to the wrong limit 1.6447253 near the 4200th term, with Kahan it gets to 1.6449339 on the 3600000th iteration. The real value is 1.644934066...

Comment: @Tux-D the question has already been asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940072/kahan-summation but IMHO without success...

Comment: @ybungalobill Instead of Kahan, what about `std::accumulate( sample.begin(), sample.end(), 0.0 );` ?

Comment: @uvts: well, it will be definitely better than the explicit loop you wrote, but it does exactly the same thing.

Comment: @ybungalobill You're right, I checked the C++ standard and it seems to me that doing Kahan would be non compliant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I DO think that mathematically the `NaN` would be more correct. In the end it's `0.0/0`. Had it been a direct division, what would have happened?

Be aware that about C++ and exceptions there are holy wars. For example read this: [To throw or not to throw exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490153/to-throw-or-not-to-throw-exceptions)

Comment: I don't see a war here. The top two answers the only ones with votes both agree. Exceptions are fine (it all depends on the situation and usage).

Comment: @Tux-D you should look at the page linked by OP. And in the end C++ isn't exactly "exception friendly" or "exception uniform" in its libraries and in the language. Sadly it's an added feature.

Answer (score 2):

I would leave the behavior undefined.

Just code it for the non-empty case and let the caller think about using it correctly. Probably you won't call it for empty vectors anyway as the check for the empty input will probably be done earlier.

Comment: undefined? And what value does your function return?

Comment: @uvts: see [undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding for using exceptions is correct and you should go ahead with that approach. Exceptions are meant for this purpose (`throw` when exceptional condition happens).

In this case, suppose if you return `NaN`, then every time you call the function `average()` you have to make sure that, you are putting an extra check which takes care of `NaN` scenario.

[Note: On top of that, make sure that the condition `(sz == 0)` is not a very frequently happening scenario. IMO, I won't use exceptions if they are thrown frequently.]

Comment: +1 I agree not using exceptions if they are thrown frequently

Comment: "every time you call the function average() you have to make sure that, you are putting an extra check which takes care of NaN scenario" - most likely the caller will ensure the input vector is non-empty (which might not require any code - in a lot of cases it will be known to be true), therefore not having to check for the NaN.

Answer (score 1):

I would throw, just to keep on the safe side and make sure the error is detected immediately and not, as you said, after a while.

in fact in this specific use case you can return 0 if it make sense to say 0 is the average of "nothing".

what we do usually is to validate parameters as soon as we get inside the method and in case we throw ArgumentNullException or OutOfRangeException if really the method was designed to only be called with non null and properly filled arguments.

Comment: I think I cannot say "0 is the average of nothing" :-), for example 0 is the average of {-1,+1}